# good way to Symfony 2 custom form validation, two choice fields

Tags: php, forms, symfony, doctrine

In Symfony2, I have adding and editing forms with two choice fields as dropdown. The first one is containing the years and the second one is containing
the weeks. so I would like to check that the selected year and week is not past time. I mean Its good to select and wanted to persist if year: 2013. and week: 5, 
but its not good if the year: 2012. and week 5. and here wanna have a warning to it.

basically I use doctrine entity manager and isValid() for validating the form right now, then I persist the object to database.

Im a little disturbed about the many ways I have found on the net.

so I would like to know which way is the best for me to validate these? I mean entity validate, non-entity, and where to search for it's place. :)

thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

I would go for CallbackValidation:

http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/reference/constraints/Callback.html

The validation is fired during the `isValid()` call so you will know when it does fail.

As for the validation code I think this should do the thing (I haven't run it yet):

```
/**
 * @Assert\Callback(methods={"isYearWeekValid"})
 */
class YourEntity
{
     ... here go $year and $week


    public function isYearWeekValid(ExecutionContext $context)
    {
        $firstInYear = \DateTime:createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $this->year . '-01-01');
        $interval = new \DateInterval(sprintf('P%dW', $this->week * 7));
        $firstDayOfWeek = $firstInYear->add($interval); # beware, $firstInYear object     was modified hear as well

        $now = new \DateTime();
        if ( $firstInWeek < $now ){
            $context->addViolation('Invalid year/week combination!', array(), null);
        }else{
            // IT'S OK
        }
    }
}
```

I used annotations to specify validation but for that purpose you could as well use `XML` or `YAML`... basically it's all the same...

Hope this helps....

Comment: thank you so much :) it is working but is there any way to do it in the entiy's controller?

Comment: If you want to rely on form's `isValid` I don't think that possible. ;) The closest thing is to add `Callback` validation to your form (within `buildForm` method). This validation is also being run during `isValid` call. Still that's pretty decoupled still it's not in entity...